# Password typed in login manager appears as username in tty

Tags: login, password, tty, plasma, sddm

The scenario I am asking about is this: when reaching the login screen after the boot process, I switch to tty2 and log in by typing my username and password. I then exit, getting back to the (graphical) login screen in tty1. I type my password there, and consequently the desktop environment is invoked. If I now switch to tty2 I see my password - fully visible - entered as the username, and the system is in the state of waiting for the password.

Further comments of possible relevance:

1. This doesn't happen if I switch to tty2 and DON'T login there, but rather switch back immediately to the login screen in tty1.
2. Exiting tty2 (with the "exit" command) makes the system switch back to the login screen in tty1 right away, without me having to hit Ctrl+Alt+1.
3. The text that ends up as the username in tty2 as described above is whatever I type as the password in the login screen, even if it's not correct.
4. Upon returning to the login screen in tty1, typing Ctrl+Alt+2 (or 3, or 4, etc.) does not switch to the corresponding tty. I have to play around with the GUI a little, clicking on various places in the screen and typing characters in the password box, to "convince" the system to accept my request to switch to another tty.

System details:

- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- Desktop environment: Plasma (package plasma-desktop's version: 4:5.12.6-0ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04~ppa1)
- Display manager: SDDM (package version: 0.17.0-1ubuntu7)

Many thanks in advance!